# Not able to insert proper "voice file(mp3) " into database

Tags: php, mysql

Able to insert the data but the format which gets inserted is not working ...tried with image files, voice files etc.

Using blob data type able to insert the file data inside the MySQL database, but the format is not working.

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "USERNAME";
$pass = "PASSWORD";
$db = "databasename";

$con = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("connection error");
}

$inscrutable = "insert into tables(id, data,filepath) values(1,'voice.mp3','F:\\\')";

if ($con->query($inscrutable) == true) {
    echo "Inserted successfully";
} else {
    echo "error" .$con->error;
}

$con->close();
```

Required to login to the page with a voice recorder

Comment: what's your table structure? You shouldn't be manually specifying ID values, they should already auto-increment

Comment: Hi ,Thank you ...i will correct id to auto increment....

Comment: Datatype of id is INT,data is longblob and filepath is varchar(100)

Comment: why is data a longblob? Surely it should just be a varchar?

Comment: Tried with varchar and it was not working that is the reason changed to longblob

Comment: You want to store the file name or the file contents ?

Comment: keep to varchar :) and try doing that SQL from the command line and seeing if the error persists

Comment: `'voice.mp3'` is just a text literal. If you want to insert the actual _content_ of the file of that name, then you need to read that content first of all, for example using `file_get_contents`. (And you will have to take care of proper _escaping_ of the data, or use prepared statements - otherwise that will most likely easily break the syntax. Please go read up on that if you don’t know what it means yet, this is basic knowledge.)

Comment: I will do the modifications as per the suggestions and will get back....thank you for help

Answer (score -1):

```
connecting database
//file_name config.php

<?php

$host = ""; /* Host name */
$user = ""; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = ""; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php
    include("config.php"); 

    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
       $maxsize = 5242880; // 5MB

       $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       $target_dir = "videos/";
       $target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

       // Select file type
       $audioFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

       // Valid file extensions
       $extensions_arr = array("MP3","WAV","FLAC","PCM","AIFF");

       // Check extension
       if( in_array($audioFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

          // Check file size
          if(($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["file"]["size"] == 0)) {
            echo "File too large. File must be less than 5MB.";
          }else{
            // Upload
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file)){
              // Insert record
              $query = "INSERT INTO tables(name,location) VALUES('".$name."','".$target_file."')";

              mysqli_query($con,$query);
              echo "Upload successfully.";
            }
          }

       }else{
          echo "Invalid file extension.";
       }

     } 
     ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'> //must use enctype = "multipart/form-data"
      <input type='file' name='file' />
      <input type='submit' value='Upload' name='upload'>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```